# Csv file containing new line (multi line)

Tags: informatica, informatica-powerexchange

We are working on a project where are planning to generate multi line csv files and load to informatica via power exchange.

Our csv file will look like as below.

```
Field1, Field2
"Row 1 Cell 1 line 1
 Row 1 Cell 1 line 2", "Row 1 Cell 2 Line 1
 Row 1 Cell 2 line 2"
 "Row 2 Cell 1 line 1
  Row 2 Cell 1 line 2", "Row 2 Cell 2 Line 1
  Row 2 Cell 2 Line 2"
```

Just wanted to check will power exchange understand this type of csv file?

**Update:** We tried loading a sample file to power exchange and it converted the new lines to space :-( Is there a way to retain then as new line and load to the data center as new line?

Answer (score 0):

Yoc can use Informatica custom properties "MatchQuotesPastEndOfLine = Yes" in Session setting

Answer (score 0):

CSV File: CSV file should be comma separated values, Multi line separation will not work. 
PowerExchange: when you create powerexchange datamaps for the csv file, you can preview the data, how the data looking there? try to play with powerexchange setting while creating the datamaps and see if you can configure some properties.